# php.ini display_errors not respected OS X Server

Tags: php

I am running an 10.6.8 OS X Server. It acts as a web server using the built in PHP and Apache.

PHP is at 5.3.4 
Apache is at 2.2.17

I am trying to disable the reporting or errors to end users with a server wide setting.

I have tried the following:

in PHP.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = Off
error_log = /dir/php_errors.log
```

The display_errors = Off is not being respected. When calling a php file that requires a string to be passed with it I will get error such as:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in ......
```

I am able to suppress the error by adding the following code to the top of the php file being called:

```
ini_set("display_errors" , "0")
```

I have also tried adding variables to various apache .conf and .htaccess .files with the following code:

```
php_value display_errors 0
```

Errors are being written to my specified log correctly. Using phpinfo() I see that I am using the correct php.ini file, and display_errors is showing off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First off using a phpinfo()... check the location of the php.ini file. It may be referencing a different one from the one you think it should be.

Comment: Using phpinfo() I see that I am using the correct php.ini file, and display_errors is showing off.